# Create POST request to tumblr

Tags: c#, api, upload, request, tumblr

I am trying to create a post request to the tumblr api. Shown below is an extract from said api:

```
The Write API is a very simple HTTP interface. To create a post, send a POST request to http://www.tumblr.com/api/write with the following parameters:
    email - Your account's email address.
    password - Your account's password.
    type - The post type.
```

These are the essential elements. I would like to send a photo to the api. According to the API, this is how I would structure my request:

```
email: myEmail
password: myPassword
type: photo
data: "c:\\img.jpg"
```

Thanks to dtb, I can send a REGULAR post, which only uses a string to send text, it does not support sending images.

```
var postData = new NameValueCollection
{
    { "email", email },
    { "password", password },
    { "type", regular },
    { "body", body }
};

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
     client.UploadValues("http://www.tumblr.com/api/write", data: data);
}
```

This works for sending a regular, however according to the API, I should send the image in a `multipart/form-data`, 
alternatively I could send it in a `Normal POST method`, 
however, filesizes are not as high as allowd with the former.


`client.UploadValues` supports data: which allows me to pass `postData` in to it. 
`client.UploadData` also does but I cannot figure out how to use it, I have referred to the documentation.
Also, an opened file cannot be passed in a NameValueCollection which baffles me as to how I could possibly send the request.

Please, if anyone knows the answer I would be extremely grateful if you would help.

Comment: The C# code snippet you show is sending a GET request. You'll need to show more if you think it is, in fact, sending a POST like your python code suggests.

Comment: @Anteara, please check my title edit - it does not look like it was reflecting what you are trying to do (add query parameters vs. post data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure this out using `RestSharp` library.

```
//Create a RestClient with the api's url
var restClient = new RestClient("http://tumblr.com/api/write");

//Tell it to send a POST request
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

//Set format and add parameters and files
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json; //I don't know if this line is necessary

request.AddParameter("email", "EMAIL");
request.AddParameter("password", "PASSWORD");
request.AddParameter("type", "photo");
request.AddFile("data", "C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Desktop\\Wallpapers\\1235698997718.jpg");

//Set RestResponse so you can see if you have an error
RestResponse response = restClient.Execute(request);
//MessageBox.Show(response) Perhaps I could wrap this in a try except?
```

It works, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it though.

If anyone has some more suggestions I will gladly take them.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`WebClient` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) and its [`UploadValues` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7.aspx) to perform a POST request with  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` payload:

```
var data = new NameValueCollection
{
    { "email", email },
    { "password", password },
    { "type", regular },
    { "body", body }
};

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
     client.UploadValues("http://www.tumblr.com/api/write", data: data);
}
```

Comment: thank you, I can post a regular post now - 
Now however I"m having trouble uploading a photo.
This is what I have:

http://pastebin.com/kUh5rj2m 

That pastebin also details what I'm using to try and post the picture. I get a cannot convert X to string for both.
Any ideas? Or am i just doing it wrong? Thanks.

Edit: I think i may have found the solution with;
'`client.UploadFile`